# javascript/jquery disable submit button on click, prevent double submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, double-submit-prevention

So I have the submit button that looks like this:

```
<a href="#" id="submitbutton" 
onClick="document.getElementById('UploaderSWF').submit();">
<img src="../images/user/create-product.png" border="0" /></a>
```

When I double click it double submits obviously, and the problem is that
I'm saving the information in the database so I'll have dublicate information there,
and I dont want that. This uploader uses flash and javscript and here is a little piece
of code that is relevant to the submit thing (if it helps)

```
$.fn.agileUploaderSubmit = function() {
    if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == '6.0') {
        window.document.agileUploaderSWF.submit();
    } else {
        document.getElementById('agileUploaderSWF').submit();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thank you guys.
I appreciate your help. This is really something I was unable to do myself
because I have such a little experience with js and I dont really know how
to do stuff.
THANKS.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this snipped:

```
$('#your_submit_id').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('disabled');
});
```

**edit 1**

Oh, in your case it is a link and no submit button ...

```
var submitted = false;

$.fn.agileUploaderSubmit = function() {
    if ( false == submitted )
    {
        submitted = true;

        if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == '6.0') {
            window.document.agileUploaderSWF.submit();
        } else {
            document.getElementById('agileUploaderSWF').submit();
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

**edit 2**

To simplify this, try this:

```
<!doctype html>

<html dir="ltr" lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#yourSubmitId').click(function()
        {
            $(this).attr('disabled',true);

            /* your submit stuff here */

            return false;
        });
    });
//--><!]]>
</script>

</head>
<body>

<form id="yourFormId" name="yourFormId" method="post" action="#">
    <input type="image" id="yourSubmitId" name="yourSubmitId" src="yourImage.png" alt="Submit" />
</form>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

</body>
</html>
```

Use form elements, like `<input type="image" />`, to submit a form not a normal link.

This works fine!

Take a look at [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to submit your form.

Good luck.

**edit 3**

This works well for me too:

```
<!doctype html>

<html dir="ltr" lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var agileUploaderSWFsubmitted = false;

        $('#submitbutton').click(function()
        {
            if ( false == agileUploaderSWFsubmitted )
            {
                agileUploaderSWFsubmitted = true;

                //console.log( 'click event triggered' );

                if ( $.browser.msie && $.browser.version == '6.0' )
                {
                    window.document.agileUploaderSWF.submit();
                }
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById( 'agileUploaderSWF' ).submit();
                }
            }

            return false;
        });
    });
//--><!]]>
</script>

</head>
<body>

<form id="agileUploaderSWF" name="agileUploaderSWF" method="post" action="http://your.action/script.php">
    <input type="text" id="agileUploaderSWF_text" name="agileUploaderSWF_text" />
</form>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

<a href="#" id="submitbutton"><img src="../images/user/create-product.png" border="0" /></a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

</body>
</html>
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Hello Raisch. Thank you for your solution. I applied your second code
and it didnt really worked. Still submits more than once. Should I apply the first block of code too?

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I'm saying it still submits twice if clicked twice. It doesnt work. Is there any other solution in your mind?
Thank you.

Comment: @bornie - Sorry, i am nearly sleeping. Try my second edit, this works for me.

Comment: You can still use the first edit. Change `if ( false == submitted )` to `if ( !submitted )`. I'm thinking that will work better.

Comment: I think your solution is the right approach to do it. Even though I think the disabled attribute should take place after
window.document.agileUploaderSWF.submit();
and/or
document.getElementById('agileUploaderSWF').submit();
so after it submits, disable it to submit twice.
Do you have any idea how to accomplish this in a way
it really works. Maybe We could do something like
hiding the submit button after it submits or something
similiar...what do you think?

Thank you for your efforts so far though.

Comment: Sometimes it is not quite as simple. We need to make sure that all the fields are valid before actually disabling the button. Otherwise you could end up with an invalid form and a disabled button.

Answer (score 5):

Add the following to the `onclick`:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('submitbutton').disabled = true;document.getElementById('UploaderSWF').submit();"
```

That said, you will have to handle this double submit prevention on the server side also.

Comment: Thanks I will try it. No problem with server side. I can do it, I'm aware that I cannot rely on js only because sometimes users disable
javascript support on their browsers.

Comment: This user is using jquery.. I don't see the need for an onClick attribute, or document.getElementById.

Comment: @bornie, I have made an edit. It was supposed to be `document.getElementById('` **`submitbutton`** `').disabled`

Comment: @Daedalus I am not sure he is using jquery to submit. His code to submit the form is `onClick="document.getElementById('UploaderSWF').submit();`. The other snippet I am not sure is relevant to the situation.

Comment: @Nivas: No need to check for double submit on the server - if the user disables JS, the form won't submit full stop! If there is an alternative for when JS is disabled then I agree, server side validation will be necessary. But given this code alone it won't be needed.

Comment: Shouldn't this use DOM2 events?

Comment: Hello. Your solution works sort of partially. When I click submit the second time it tries to connect with the form processor but doesnt succeeds. That isnt really helpful because I want to disable
the button (to be unclickable) and let the form submit. I want to totally ignore other clicks. The way it is now, the form simply stucks and doesnt proceed to the other page, that is important because this is how the user is going to find out that the form was submitted.
Can you fix something about this one?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will disable all submit buttons and links with the class submit or the attribute data-submit in a form if one is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        $(this).find('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);
        $(this).find('a[data-submit], a.submit').click(function() {
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

This automatically applies to every form, by the way. If you just want a certain one, use the id instead of form. You most probably already knew that, though.

Comment: Well the problem is that if you can see more carefully, the submit button is not within <form></form>. It is separated. You think your code is still valid?

Answer (score 0):

According to http://api.jquery.com/prop/ 
you can be add and remove the disabled property using the .prop() function, not the .attr() and .removeAttr() functions.

To add the property:

```
.prop("disabled", true);
```

To remove the property:

```
.prop("disabled", false);
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556571/prevent-click-event-from-firing-multiple-times-issue-with-fading/58854220#58854220) (with examples):

if you want to make sure that the registered event is fired only once, you should use jQuery's [one][1] :

> .one( events [, data ], handler ) Returns: jQuery
>
> Description: Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.