# Clicking multiple times on a show/hide function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made this something like this: 
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/bolbol550/details/wvMKeXO) or code down.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var btn1Status = 0;
  $("button").click(function () {
    if (btn1Status === 0) {
      $(".info").slideDown();
      $(".info").show("slow");
      $("button").text("less");
      btn1Status = 1;
    } else {
      $(".info").slideUp();
      $(".nfo").hide("slow");
      btn1Status = 0;
      $("button").text("More");
    }

  });
  });
```

```css
button {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
}
button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0;
}

.info {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: arial;
  width: 400px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div><img src="https://img.favpng.com/22/6/0/portable-network-graphics-movie-camera-film-clip-art-computer-icons-png-favpng-qfZ7hHPN2CCxiK8sYfjS2Sti9.jpg" width="400"><button>More</button></div>

<div class="info">
  <ul>
    <li>Name: movie1</li>
    <li>Time: 6:00PM</li>
    <li>Info 3 : blablabla</li>
    <li>Info 4 : blablabla</li>               
    </ul>
</div>
```

when someone clicks the button, the info div should appear. the problem is, if I click the button multiple times then lift it, it will keep showing and disappearing. How do I fix this problem. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent 'click' event from firing multiple times + issue with fading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556571/prevent-click-event-from-firing-multiple-times-issue-with-fading)

Comment: Refer: https://api.jquery.com/show/#show-duration-complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the ability to let the users click multiple times but not build a queue of animations you can use the [stop](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) function from jQuery to stop/clear the queue of any currently running animations.

```
if (btn1Status === 0) {
  $(".info").stop(true, true).slideDown();
  $(".info").show("slow");
  $("button").text("less");
  btn1Status = 1;
} else {
  $(".info").stop(true, true).slideUp();
  $(".info").hide("slow");
  btn1Status = 0;
  $("button").text("More");
}
```

This will cancel the queue of animations if the button is clicked multiple times. The two arguments of `.stop()` are: `( [clearQueue ] [, jumpToEnd ] )`. clearQueue is needed to clear the current animation queue, jumpToEnd will either cancel the currently running animation before jumping to the next one, or begin running the next slide animation from the current animation frame.

Comment: can you tell me what the true_s_ are for

Comment: Edited my post to include information on the arguments for `.stop()`